# yii 1 и JSON ответ от AJAX запроса

Tags: ajax, json, yii

В Yii2 есть такой метод Yii::$app->response->format = 'json'; оп поваляет вернуть ответ аякса в формате JSON , а кто знает как этот же метод воспроизвести в Yii 1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Установить заголовки, и вернуть ответ:

```
public function actionTest(){
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    ...
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего только по-старинке через `json_encode`, пример:

```
if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
    exit(json_encode($data));
```